# Angular material tabs animation breaks when using routerLink

Tags: angular-material, angular-router, angular6, angular-animations

I'm implementing angular material tabs in my angular 6 application. If I use the material tabs without binding to routerLink then the sliding animation works and the content in router outlet works. However when I bind to routerLink the sliding animation doesn't work and the content just appears in a very clunky way.

```
<div class="my-3">
    <nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
        <a mat-tab-link
            *ngFor="let tab of tabs"
            [routerLink]="tab.path"
            routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive"
            [active]="rla.isActive">
            {{tab.label}}
        </a>
   </nav>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The paths are declared inside of the component template:

```
tabs: any[] = [
    {
        label: "Details",
        path: "details"
    },
    {
        label: "Users",
        path: "users"
    }
]
```

And the modules are loaded lazily.

Does anyone know why the animation breaks? I have done some digging around to find an answer. I am importing BrowserAnimationsModule from '@angular/platform-browser/animations' in app module and I am not declaring any NoopBrowserAnimations anywhere either.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing that you must define animations for router outlet. If you happened to resolve that please post it:)

Answer (score 3):

In order to achieve tabs animation on `mat-tab-link` as on regular `mat-tab` you need to define a route animation for your `<router-outlet>`.

Here is a good example on route animations:
https://angular.io/guide/route-animations